# If manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected, $M_1\# M_2$ is connected.

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

Show that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected $n$-manifolds and $n>1$, then $M_1 \# M_2$ is connected.

$M_1 \# M_2$ is the [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) of the two manifolds.

This is problem 4.18(b) from Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds. My proof:

A theorem from the book furnishes, *mutatis mutandis*, topological embeddings $e_i:M_i^\prime\to M_1 \# M_2$ such that:
$$e_1(M_1^\prime) \bigcup e_2(M_2^\prime) = M_1 \# M_2$$
$$e_1(M_1^\prime) \bigcap e_2(M_2^\prime) = e_1(\partial M_1^\prime) = e_2(\partial M_2^\prime)$$
where $M_i^\prime = M_i \backslash B_i$ is the manifold with boundary that is formed by taking a regular coordinate ball from $M_i$ (the boundaries of the $M_i^\prime$ are joined to form the connected sum).

Since the $M_i^\prime$ have nonempty boundary, $e_1(M_1^\prime) \bigcap e_2(M_2^\prime) \neq \emptyset$. Now, $e_i(M_i^\prime)$ being a topological embedding, it is connected if and only if $M_i^\prime$ is connected, which is true if $M_i$ is connected.

So assuming that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected, this shows that $M_1 \# M_2$ is the union of nonempty connected sets with nonempty intersection, which implies that it is connected.

This seems to be correct but I never had to assume that $n>1$, which troubles me. Is this condition necessary? Intuitively, it doesn't seem to be, so I'm confused. Let me know where I went wrong, if I did, but please don't just give the correct answer.

Comment: Removing a ball from a connected manifold of dimension 1 may disconnect it

Comment: @Pedro Thank you very much, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following manifolds $(0,3)\times \{0\}$, $(0,3)\times \{1\}$. Remove the balls $(1,2)\times \{0\}$ and $(1,2)\times \{ 1\}$. Now glue $(0,1)\times\{0\}$ to $(0,1)\times \{1\}$ and $(2,3)\times\{0\}$ to $(2,3)\times \{1\}$. Then you end up with two lines, which is not connected.

**Added:**
The problem is (as Pedro already said in the comment) that in dimension one removing a ball may disconnect the manifold (which is exactly what happens in the example above).

Comment: Is the "gluing" in this case the same thing as forming the connected sum though? The points you have deleted from the manifolds aren't regular coordinate balls, since you end up with four manifolds (without boundary) after they are deleted. At least in this book, the connected sum is by definition formed by removing regular coordinate balls and attaching along the boundaries formed.

Comment: @Shaun_the_Post Of course you're right. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. The dimensional restriction comes in when you arguing that $M_i\smallsetminus B_i$ is connected when $M_i$ is. To show this, it is equal to show that $M_i \smallsetminus B_i$ is path-connected. When we're done showing this, the rest of the arguments follows the same route as yours.

To show $M \smallsetminus B$ is path-connected, let $p,q \in M'=M\smallsetminus B$ be arbitrary and let $\alpha : [0,1] \to M$ be a path connecting them (guaranteed by hypothesis). If this path does not intersect $B$, then we are done. That is we obtain a path in $M'$  connecting $p$ and $q$. If it does intersect $B$, we do the following: let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be the minimum and the maximum of the closed subset $\alpha^{-1}(\bar{B}) \subseteq [0,1]$ respectively. That is $\alpha(t_1)$ is the point where the path  hit $\bar{B}$ for the first time and $\alpha(t_2)$ is the point where the path is on $\bar{B}$ for the last time. Both of this points must lie on the boundary $\partial \bar{B}$. Since $B$ is a regular coordinate ball, $\partial \bar{B}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and hence $\partial \bar{B}$ is connected (this is where the dimensional restriction comes in). Choose a path (after rescaling the parameter) $\beta : [t_1,t_2] \to \partial \bar{B}$ connecting $\alpha(t_1)$ and $\alpha(t_2)$, define a new path $\alpha' : [0,1] \to M \smallsetminus B$ as
    \begin{equation*}
 \alpha'(t) =  \left\{
 \begin{array}{rl}
 \alpha(t) & \text{for } 0 \leq t \leq t_1,\\
 \beta(t) & \text{for } t_1 \leq t \leq t_2,\\
 \alpha(t) & \text{for } t_2 \leq t \leq 1.
 \end{array} \right.
 \end{equation*}
    Therefore we obtained a path in $M'$ joining $p$ and $q$.